# DELETE of old rows causing deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I have two SQL Server tables. Table1 is a live table to store live events from users, the other table, Table2 is storing these events as historical data for archive purposes.

When INSERT happens on Table1 a trigger INSERTs that data to Table2 and DELETEs old rows from both tables with different time intervals.

When I'm using only INSERT to Table2 and DELETE FROM table1 everything goes alright, but when It goes to deletion of the old files on table2 I've got deadlock.
Can anyone give me some hints why this can happen and what can be the cause? (I'm newbie, sorry)

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_events ON dbo.TAble1 
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.TAble2
        (id, event_time, resource_type)
  SELECT id, event_time, resource_type FROM inserted WITH (NOLOCK);

  DECLARE @done_main bit = 0;
  WHILE (@done_main = 0)
  BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(1000) FROM dbo.TAble1 WHERE EVENT_TIME < (SELECT cast(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',(DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE())))AS bigint)* 1000 );
    IF @@rowcount < 1000 SET @done_main = 1;
  END;
  DECLARE @done bit = 0;
  WHILE (@done = 0)
  BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(1000) FROM dbo.TAble2 WHERE EVENT_TIME < (SELECT cast(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())))AS bigint)* 1000 );
    IF @@rowcount < 1000 SET @done = 1;
  END;
  
GO
```

Comment: Can you post the .xdl somewhere? Also nothing to do with your problem but why do you think you need a `NOLOCK` hint against `inserted`? Why are you doing this table maintenance inside a trigger (all of that work is going to be part of the transaction on the insert - much better to do that maintenance with a background process).

Comment: The fact you have a `WHILE` in a `TRIGGER` doesn't surprise me that you're getting deadlocks, if I am honest. And an `INSERT INTO` with a `NOLOCK` from `inserted`? Really? Do you know what `NOLOCK` does? It makes *literally* no sense against the pseudo table.

Comment: Sorry, NOLOCK isn't there, I accidently put that here. This is of course just a sample code of my trigger.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks! How would you move the maintenance to background process? I'm just learning here guys :)

Comment: You create a stored procedure that performs those deletes and schedule it in a job as frequently as you think you need to.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - thanks, I think it will be enough for me!

Comment: We need to see the full `.xdl`, along with table and index definitions, and please share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: At a guess, you need an index on `TAble1 (EVENT_TIME)` and `TAble2 (EVENT_TIME)`